# Is Sys.WORD_SIZE guaranteed to match the default integer size?

Tags: julia

The section of the [Julia documentation for Integers](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/integers-and-floating-point-numbers/#Integers) describes the default type (size) of an integer [with `Int` being an alias for either `Int32` or `Int64`]:

> The default type for an integer literal depends on whether the target system has a 32-bit architecture or a 64-bit architecture

There is also a definition of the `Sys.WORD_SIZE` variable:

> The Julia internal variable Sys.WORD_SIZE indicates whether the target system is 32-bit or 64-bit

However, the variation in terminology (the first refers to "architecture" while the second doesn't) allows for some ambiguity regarding "system" vs. "architecture".

Are there any circumstances where the default size of an integer and `Sys.WORD_SIZE` would not match?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, `Sys.WORD_SIZE` is defined in terms of the size of `Int`. See https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/master/base/sysinfo.jl.

```
"""
    Sys.WORD_SIZE::Int
Standard word size on the current machine, in bits.
"""
const WORD_SIZE = Core.sizeof(Int) * 8
```